# "Time-lapse" using plt.pause() [SOLVED]

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a 1-dim plot, which plots the value in 10 columns at a certain point in time and I would like to be able to see how it changes "live".

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')

path_temp = '/mnt/sd-card/Dropbox/Documents/exjobb/temp/'
ext = '.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path_temp+'df_master'+ext)
loggers3 = ['20796674', '15617', '15592', '15606', '15543', '20796679', '15610', '15566', '15565', '20796630']
timestamp = ['2022-03-13 00:00:00', '2022-03-13 01:00:00', '2022-03-13 02:00:00', '2022-03-13 03:00:00', '2022-03-13 04:00:00', '2022-03-13 05:00:00', '2022-03-13 06:00:00', '2022-03-13 07:00:00', '2022-03-13 08:00:00', '2022-03-13 09:00:00', '2022-03-13 10:00:00', '2022-03-13 11:00:00', '2022-03-13 12:00:00', '2022-03-13 13:00:00', '2022-03-13 14:00:00', '2022-03-13 15:00:00', '2022-03-13 16:00:00', '2022-03-13 17:00:00', '2022-03-13 18:00:00', '2022-03-13 19:00:00', '2022-03-13 20:00:00', '2022-03-13 21:00:00', '2022-03-13 22:00:00', '2022-03-13 23:00:00']
target_column = 'Diff '
target_name = 'Diff '

plt.figure()

for time in timestamp:

    data = df.loc[df['TIMESTAMP'] == time]
    
    column_names = [target_name+i for i in loggers3]
    
    pressures = data[column_names].iloc[0]
    
    colnames = [column for column in df.columns if target_column in column] 
    del colnames[10:12]
       
    plt.plot(colnames, pressures.values, '-o', label = time)
    
plt.legend()
plt.pause(0.1)
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how `plt.pause()` works, but it would be great to have it implemented in this plot somehow.

Comment: Any other way of animated plot is also welcome.

Comment: put the `plt.pause(0.1)` inside the for loop

Comment: Oh... Of course! Thanks! One step in the right direction! =D
Next question: Is it possible to not stack the plots on top of each other, and just show one on each "tick"?

Comment: Adding plt.clf() sorted it out. All good now! Thanks, @tmdavison

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the object oriented approach: create a Figure and Axes instance before your loop with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then use the `ax.plot()` method rather than `plt.plot()`, to ensure all lines are drawn on the same figure.

Comment: I think I'll just stick to the first one instead.

Comment: Running this code does raise another question though. Why isn't the label showing? I'd like to be able to view how the plot changes according to the date.

Comment: Actually, I'm starting a new question fr this. 

Thanks a ton for helping me out with the main issue.